# Creating a JSON array from two lists using pandas

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, list

Is is possible to zip two lists into a JSON array?

Input:

```
    keys=["['os','dist','rel','flag']",
          "['os','dist']",
          "['os','dist','rel']",
          "['os','version','rel','flag']"]
    vals=["['linux','centos','9','y']",
         "['linux','ubuntu']",
         "['linux','rhel','8']",
         "['linux','8','.03','y']"]
    df=pd.DataFrame({'key':keys,'val':vals})
```

Desired Output:

```
{'key':'os','val':'linux'},{'key':'dist','val':'rhel'},{'key':'rel','val':'9'},{'key':'flag','val':'y'}
...
...
```

I am new to python and tried several different combinations of list/map/lambda/zip and no success thus far.

Comment: You have a string representation of a list inside of a list? And you want to take that string representation and turn it into a proper list, and then, disregarding one of the two dimensions string together a list of dictionaries? Are you sure? Both the input and the output is odd. Is there some bigger problem you are trying to solve that has led you down this path?

Comment: Are you quite sure that's the data structure you have?  Because that's very odd.  You have two lists of strings.  It's not a list of lists, because they are in quotes, and it's not JSON because they use single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, but you certainly don't need or want pandas for this.  My guess is this is not the actual result you want, but here's how to do it.

```
import ast

keys=["['os','dist','rel','flag']",
      "['os','dist']",
      "['os','dist','rel']",
      "['os','version','rel','flag']"]
vals=["['linux','centos','9','y']",
     "['linux','ubuntu']",
     "['linux','rhel','8']",
     "['linux','8','.03','y']"]

keys = [ast.literal_eval(k) for k in keys]
vals = [ast.literal_eval(v) for v in vals]

results = [] 
for kk,vv in zip(keys, vals):
    results.extend( [{'key': k, 'val': v} for k,v in zip(kk,vv)] )

from pprint import pprint
pprint(results)
```

Output:

```
[{'key': 'os', 'val': 'linux'},
 {'key': 'dist', 'val': 'centos'},
 {'key': 'rel', 'val': '9'},
 {'key': 'flag', 'val': 'y'},
 {'key': 'os', 'val': 'linux'},
 {'key': 'dist', 'val': 'ubuntu'},
 {'key': 'os', 'val': 'linux'},
 {'key': 'dist', 'val': 'rhel'},
 {'key': 'rel', 'val': '8'},
 {'key': 'os', 'val': 'linux'},
 {'key': 'version', 'val': '8'},
 {'key': 'rel', 'val': '.03'},
 {'key': 'flag', 'val': 'y'}]
```

Comment: It's such an odd output. I can't help but think that a more sensible output that doesn't destroy the relationship of the inner lists would be `results = [[{k:v} for k,v in zip(kk,vv)] for kk,vv in zip(keys, vals)]`, even though OP asked exactly for the output you are generating 

Comment: You're absolutely right, and in fact when I wrote this response, that's exactly what I had the code produce, because I assumed that would be right.  I was just about to post the output when I realized it didn't match what he said.

Comment: I had to write that code just to scratch the itch and set everything right with the world .